# How to run tasks that use same external variables?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a web service (*ExternalWebService*) that receives a period (*start* and *end* date) and returns all logs for this period, and I want to make a call for this service passing a long period. The problem is that this service allows only a small amount of data to be sent per request, and long periods means large amount of data, what causes an error. So, I decided to loop through the months of the period passed as parameter and make calls for this service in parallel using tasks, concatenating the results at the end of the execution of the tasks. Here is the code:

```
public List<object> GetList(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<object> finalList = new List<object>();
    object lockList = new object();

    DateTime current = start;

    List<Task> threads = new List<Task>();

    do
    {
        current = new DateTime(Math.Min(current.AddMonths(1).Ticks, end.Ticks));

        Task thread = Task.Run(() => {
            List<object> partialList = ExternalWebService.GetListByPeriod(from: start, to: current);
            lock (lockList)
            {
                finalList = finalList.Concat(partialList).ToList();
            }
        });

        threads.Add(thread);

        start = current;
    }
    while (current < end);

    Task.WhenAll(threads).Wait();

    return finalList;
}
```

This code works but has an unexpected result, because the variables *start* and *current* change before being used inside the thread. So, what can I do to guarantee that the *start* and *current* date used inside *Task.Run* have the same values they had when the thread was created?

Comment: Your main issue here is that your setting `start = current` without awaiting the `Task` you spun off, i.e. your changing the dates before the task can use them.

Comment: Exactly, but I can´t await the Task because I need to start the next Task and continue the loop. I will only await for the tasks at the end.

Comment: I'm following you, hopefully my answer below will get you in the right direction. There's no need to mutate those dates, you can keep the dates you need as locals. Also, the method in the answer does away with the unnecessary lock since it's not sharing and mutating the list either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that receives the `DateTime` you want and return the delegate to pass it to the `Task.Run` method, something like:

```
private Action GetMethodAction(DateTime current) 
{
     return () => { /* your code here */ }
}
```

That way the value of `current` is bound to the action you are returning. Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked just fine! I will post the complete answer.
I was wondering why using a method the variables are passed by value whilst the inline method uses the reference?

Answer (score 3):

It would be best not to both share and mutate your dates. You can spin up a set of tasks that query your web service asynchronously and flatten the results.

```
public class GetData {

    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetDataAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
        var daysPerChunk = 28;
        var totalChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((endDate - startDate).TotalDays / daysPerChunk);
        var chunks = Enumerable.Range(0, totalChunks);

        var dataTasks = chunks.Select(chunkIndex => {
            var start = startDate.AddDays(chunkIndex * daysPerChunk);
            var end = new DateTime(Math.Min(start.AddDays(daysPerChunk).Ticks, endDate.Ticks));
            return ExternalWebService.GetListByPeriodAsync(from: start, to: end);
        });
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(dataTasks);

        var data = results.SelectMany(_ => _);
        return data.ToList();
    }
}

public class ExternalWebService {

    private static HttpClient Client {
        get;
    } = new HttpClient();


    public async static Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetListByPeriodAsync(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("GetListByPeriodFromToUri");
        if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                    var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<object>>(str);
                }
            }
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work but I don´t have access to the ExternalWebService. I am just consuming this service from another company.

Comment: @Marcello Are you calling their web service with a url? If so you can make the call async.

Comment: @Marcello Alos, note that this doesn't need to be done async. This method could just as easily be turned into a `AsParallel` `SelectMany`. But if you're going on the wire it's best to go async.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer that worked for me without changing a lot the code. I am gonna try this code now to see if it works for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
protected override List<object> GetList(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    object lockList = new object();

    DateTime current = start;

    List<Task> threads = new List<Task>();

    do
    {
        current = new DateTime(Math.Min(current.AddMonths(1).Ticks, end.Ticks));

        Task thread = Task.Run(GetMethodFunc(start, current)).ContinueWith((result) => 
        {
            lock (lockList)
            {
                list = list.Concat(result.Result).ToList();
            }
        });

        threads.Add(thread);

        start = current;
    }
    while (current < end);

    Task.WhenAll(threads).Wait();

    return list;
}

private Func<List<object>> GetMethodFunc(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return () => {
        List<object> partialList = ExternalWebService.GetListByPeriod(from: start, to: end);
        return partialList;
    };
}
```